# Using property from @TestPropertySource properties results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, spring-boot, spring-test

I have the following test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest

@TestPropertySource(value = "classpath:testApplication.properties")
public class ESJavaAPITests {

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    private final String    CLUSTER_NAME    = environment.getProperty("ES.cluster.name");
}
```

The properties is located in `test/java/resources/testApplication.properties` and looks lie this:

```
ES.host = localhost
ES.port = 9300
ES.cluster.name = 2m3d
```

However I keep getting the `NullPointerException` line 25 which is exactly the line with `CLUSTER_NAME` initialization:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.example.estrans.ESJavaAPITests.(ESJavaAPITests.java:25)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Why an NPE?

Comment: Try @ Autowired instead of @ Resource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an NPE because at the moment your `CLUSTER_NAME` field is initialized the environment is `null` because Spring hasn't had the time to autowire the class yet - `CLUSTER_NAME` is initialized when the test class instance is created. You should use `@Value("${ES.cluster.name}")` instead:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(value = "classpath:testApplication.properties")
public class ESJavaAPITests {

    @Value("${ES.cluster.name}")
    private String CLUSTER_NAME;
}
```